# In formArray disable particular fields on add button

Tags: javascript, html, angular

After binding data in Formarray. we can edit formarray but in this case we want one particular fields

So whenever click pulse button(+) need to enable secret key fields. by default secret key disable
what I am facing when I am doing enable previous value also enable I don't want enable previous only I want only current fields enable

UI screen
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y35eu.png)

Comment: can you attach the component and template code

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.